# Firebase calendar (Multi-User)

Tags: qt, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, calendar

I am currently building a multi-user calendar app in Qt, and intend to use firebase realtime database to handle the user data and scheduled tasks.

Each user can login to the app and select days which,  once clicking on a 'save' button, will be locked to their name. I have no previous experience with firebase and would like some help to begin structuring the database, I want to be able to separate users into departments also.

Below is the code of my calendar page on my app, what would I put into firebase to be able to connect the two?

any help would be much appreciated!!

```
Page {

    title: "Calendar"

    rightBarItem: NavigationBarItem {
      contentWidth: saveButton.width

      AppButton {
          id: saveButton
          text: "Save & Request"
          anchors.right: parent.right
      }
    }


    SystemPalette {
        id: systemPalette
    }

    Flow {
        id: row
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 10
        layoutDirection: "RightToLeft"
        Calendar {
            id: calendar
            width: (parent.width > parent.height ? parent.width * 0.6 - parent.spacing : parent.width)
            height: (parent.height > parent.width ? parent.height * 0.6 - parent.spacing : parent.height)
            selectedDate: new Date()
            focus: true


           style: CalendarStyle {
               dayDelegate: Item {
                   readonly property color sameMonthDateTextColor: "#444"
                   readonly property color selectedDateColor: Qt.platformos === "osx" ? "#3778d0" : systemPalette.highlight
                   readonly property color selectedDateTextColor: "white"
                   readonly property color differentMonthDateTextColor: "#bbb"
                   readonly property color invalidDatecolor: "#dddddd"

                   Rectangle {
                       anchors.fill: parent
                       border.color: "#00000000"
                       color: styleData.date !== undefined && styleData.selected? selectedDateColor : "#00000000"
                       anchors.margins: styleData.selected ? -1 : 0
                   }

                   Label {
                       id: dayDelegateText
                       text: styleData.date.getDate()
                       anchors.centerIn: parent
                       color:  {
                           var color = invalidDatecolor;
                           if (styleData.valid) {
                               color = styleData.visibleMonth ? sameMonthDateTextColor : differentMonthDateTextColor ;
                               if (styleData.selected) {
                                   color = selectedDateTextColor;
                               }
                           }
                           color ;
                       }
                   }
               }

           }

        }

        Component {
            id: eventListHeader

            Row {
                id: eventDateRow
                width: parent.width
                height: eventDayLabel.height
                spacing: 10

                Label {
                    id: eventDayLabel
                    text: calendar.selectedDate.getDate()
                    font.pointSize: 35
                }
                Column {
                    height: eventDayLabel.height

                    Label {
                        readonly property var options: { weekday: "long" }
                        text: Qt.locale().standaloneDayName(calendar.selectedDate.getDay(), Locale.LongFormat)
                        font.pointSize: 18
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: Qt.locale().standaloneMonthName(calendar.selectedDate.getMonth())
                              + calendar.selectedDate.toLocaleDateString(Qt.locale(), " yyyy")
                        font.pointSize: 12
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            width: (parent.width > parent.height ? parent.width * 0.4 - parent.spacing : parent.width)
            height: (parent.height > parent.width ? parent.height * 0.4 - parent.spacing : parent.height)

            ListView {
                id:eventListView
                spacing: 4
                clip: true
                header: eventListHeader
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 10
                model: eventModel.eventsForDate(calendar.selectedDate)

                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: eventListView.width
                    height: eventItemColumn.height
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

                    Image {
                        anchors.top: parent.top
                        anchors.topMargin: 4
                        width: 12
                        height: width
                        source: "qrc:/images/eventindicator.png"
                    }
                    Rectangle {
                        width: parent.width
                        height: 1
                        color: "#eee"
                    }
                    Column {
                        id: eventItemColumn
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                        anchors.leftMargin: 20
                        anchors.right: parent.right
                        height: timeLabel.height + nameLabel.height + 8

                        Label {
                            id: nameLabel
                            width: parent.width
                            wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                            text: modelData.name
                        }
                        Label {
                            id: timeLabel
                            width: parent.width
                            wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                            text: modelData.startDate.toLocaleTimeString(calendar.locale, Locale.ShortFormat)
                            color: "#aaa"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @eyllanesc, If I am correct you have lined several lines of my posted code, could you explain your reasons for doing this, do you think they are not needed in my given example?

Comment: Hey @eyllanesc 
My laptop said 620 lines edited which is why I was a little confused! 
I have nothing against it at all haha! I'm on here seeking help/advice from the more experienced so the more help I can get the better! 

Thanks!

Comment: Going to your question, Firebase does not come with Qt, rather there is no Qt module that provides access to Firebase so instead of placing a lot of code you focus on the specific question and provide a [mcve] in addition to indicating which module or how you access Firebase, read [ask]

Comment: @eyllanesc I am using a Firebase plugin within my ide which allows access to Firebase authentication & realtime database, and was advised elsewhere that with my intended app use Firebase would be the best path to follow. I completely understand minimal code in questions to not confuse things with invalid code but where the segment contains the functioning page i thought it may be applicable in this sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have not yet integrated Firebase to your Qt project?

You can have a look at this plugin for using Firebase with Qt Quick: https://v-play.net/doc/plugin-firebase/

Then you can listen to the [reatimeValueChanged](https://v-play.net/doc/vplayplugins-firebasedatabase/#realtimeUserValueChanged-signal) signal and update your calendar accordingly.